# HTML/Ajax online Configurator with colors and shapes

Tags: javascript

based to your experience, what kind of technical solution will you apply to build an online product configurator where users can change colors and textures upon the product?

Think about a simple t-shirt, with many colors and textures that users can apply to it. Which solution will be the best to implement this configurator with HTML and Javascript, without having to deal with thousands of real photos?

Was thinking about an SVG or Canvas implementation, but I think will be hard.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use some SVG library (I would prefer `svg` over `canvas`) you should be able to do it very easily.

I would suggest you take a look at: http://raphaeljs.com/. Really awesome library...

Comment: Wow, I knew that library but I never read carefully its documentation. Thanks a lot